# Using TypeScript with DataTables, how do I work out the correct type for 'this'

Tags: jquery, typescript, datatables

I'm using some code from the following page:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()

specifically

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();



table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        that
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
} );
```

How do I know what type to use for the two instances of 'this' in the code?

I've tried printing this.constructor.name but it just return 's' and that doesn't seem to help determine the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `this` is typed by the data table typings:

```
every(fn: (this: ColumnMethods, colIdx: number, tableLoop: number, colLoop: number) => void): Api;
```

The second this will implicitly be an HTMLElement and this is determined by the definition of `on` and `JQuery.EventHandler`

```
interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> extends Iterable<TElement> {
    on(events: string,
       handler: JQuery.EventHandler<TElement> | JQuery.EventHandlerBase<any, JQuery.Event<TElement>> | false): this;
}

interface EventHandler<TCurrentTarget, TData = null> extends EventHandlerBase<TCurrentTarget, Event<TCurrentTarget, TData>> { }
interface EventHandlerBase<TContext, T> {
    // The source of the type for this, some generics involved 
    (this: TContext, t: T, ...args: any[]): void | false | any;
}
```

To access the `value` property we should be explicit when we invoke `$` and specify the type of `HTMLElement` we expect and this will type `this` inside the handler we pass to `on` correctly.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.columns().every(function () {
    var that: DataTables.ColumnMethods = this; // redundant but we can specify it
    // We can specify the result we expect to the $ function 
    $<HTMLInputElement>('input').on('keyup change', function () { // required to access value
        that
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    });
})
```